# Ruby 2.3 write UTF-16LE gzip file

Tags: ruby, file, encoding, utf-16, ruby-2.3

I have this code, running with Ruby 2.3.1:

```
str = "麦克风访问被拒绝"
puts str.encoding #=> "UTF-8"

conv = Encoding::Converter.new("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE")
str = conv.convert(str)
puts str.encoding #=> "UTF-16LE"

Zlib::GzipWriter.open("test.gz", encoding: "UTF-16LE") do |gz|
  puts str.encoding #=> "UTF-16LE"
  gz.write(str)
end

Zlib::GzipReader.open("test.gz") do |gz|
  puts gz.read.encoding #=> ASCII-8BIT
  gz.read
end
```

and returns [Invalid encoding]

How can I save file in a way that it keeps the encoding as UTF-16LE?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I'm concerned (And confirmed by the Docs), you cannot send an options hash to the `.open`-function. You'll have to create an object first, using `Zlib::GzipWriter.new(io, level = nil, strategy = nil, options = {})`, as noted in the [Docs](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Zlib/GzipWriter.html).

```
require 'zlib'

str = "麦克风访问被拒绝"

conv = Encoding::Converter.new("UTF-8", "UTF-16LE")
str = conv.convert(str)
p str

File.open('test.gz', 'w') do |f|
  gz = Zlib::GzipWriter.new(f, nil, nil, encoding: 'UTF-16LE' )
  gz.write str
  gz.close
end

File.open('test.gz') do |f|
  gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(f, { encoding: 'UTF-16LE' })
  p gz.read
  gz.close
end
```

This code outputs:

```
\u9EA6\u514B\u98CE\u8BBF\u95EE\u88AB\u62D2\u7EDD

\u9EA6\u514B\u98CE\u8BBF\u95EE\u88AB\u62D2\u7EDD
```

(Updated - Fixed entire example, working)